# openGL camera issue

Tags: opengl, graphics, camera, rendering, textures

So I'm having a little trouble getting the openGL camera to do what I want. Basically I want it to move to a certain location based on my keyboard input, render the scene to a texture, then move back to its previous location and then render the texture to a quad. The effect I want to go for is the scene moving around on my quad while the quad stays still. However no matter what I do the quad itself always winds up moving along with the texture.

I'm basically doing the following:

```
SetMatrices;
gluLookAt(randomposition);
renderSceneToTexture;
gluLookAt(originalPosition)
texturemap my quad/render to screen.
```

What am I missing here? My rendering code is fine because when I don't mess around with the camera everything renders correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the identity matrix, (or some other canonical matrix which you set up in `SetMatrices`) before you use `gluLookAt`, `gluLookAt` multiplies a new matrix with the existing modelview matrix.

Alternatively you can use the push and pop matrix way of working:

- set up your matrices
- push the modelview matrix
- look at random position
- render scene to texture
- pop the modelview matrix
- look at original position (may not be necessary)
- render your quad

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I didn't realize that calling gluLookAt worked as a matrix transformation.

Comment: You need to realize that there is no such thing as a camera in OpenGL, everything is matrix transformations. It is not necessary to have separate camera and scene concepts, since whether you move the camera or move the scene in the opposite way will give the same effect. That is why the modelview matrix simply describes a single transformation which is the delta between what you would see as the "camera" and the "scene."